# Android Studio components not centering correctly when tested on an external device

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, layout

I have a simple app written in Java that I am trying to make work on Android devices. The code runs without issue, but the layout of the widgets is inconsistent.

I want all of them to be centered on the screen, and this works when I run the program in an emulator from Android Studio- I have tried this with an emulated Nexus 6P and a Pixel 3A.

However, when I run the program on a physical device, a Galaxy S9, some of the widgets are no longer centered.

I have tried centering the gravity for the RelativeLayout, and using android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" for each of the widgets. I also tried setting the size of the widgets to match_parent and then centering the gravity horizontally inside them. So far this has all given the same result.

I include the XML code below, along with two screenshots for comparison, one from the emulated Nexus 6P and one from the Galaxy S9. You should see that the button and the number field are centered, but all of the text is slightly off-centre.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:editable="false"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Arby's Hi-Lo Guessing Game"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPrompt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="-2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        android:text="Enter a number between 1 and 100:"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtGuess"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="166dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="166dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGuess"
        android:layout_width="126dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
        android:text="Guess!" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblOutput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Enter a number, then click Guess!"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[Emulator Alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXPJb.png)

[Physical Device Alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTtzJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your views have absolute margins set in `dp`. These will not look the same on different sized screens. Remove all `marginStart`, `marginEnd`, `marginRight` and `marginLeft` attributes. Then `RelativeLayout` should center the views properly.

Answer (score 0):

try this, i did it fast but i hope it wiill work ;)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:editable="false"
    android:text="Arby's Hi-Lo Guessing Game"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
    android:visibility="visible"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtPrompt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:text="Enter a number between 1 and 100:"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtGuess"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPrompt"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:inputType="number" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnGuess"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtGuess"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_width="126dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Guess!" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblOutput"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnGuess"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Enter a number, then click Guess!"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```